# XKB Programming Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want to make a XKB/symbols file for programming in Processing (kind of like Java, but not quite).
For example, if I press <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> I want it to make a for loop, i.e.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < ; i++) {

}
```

and then put my cursor right before the second `;`.

I've done some in XKB before, but nothing involving doing multiple things per key like this.

If it’s not possible in XKB, any other solution that would work is good.

Here's the entire file, for reference:

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    name[Group1]= "Processing";

    //Row 1
    key <TLDE> {    [        exclam,    exclam equal    ]   };//grave to exclam
    key <AE01> {    [             1     ]   };
    key <AE02> {    [             2,    at      ]   };
    key <AE03> {    [             3,    numbersign  ]   };
    key <AE04> {    [             4,    dollar      ]   };
    key <AE05> {    [             5,    percent     ]   };
    key <AE06> {    [             6,    Left p o w parenleft Right comma space parenright Left  ]   };
    key <AE07> {    [             7,    ampersand ampersand ]   };
    key <AE08> {    [             8,    bar bar     ]   };
    key <AE09> {    [             9,    bracketleft ]   };//Switched parenleft  with bracketleft
    key <AE10> {    [             0,    bracketright    ]   };//Switched parenright with bracketright
    key <AE11> {    [     backslash,    underscore  ]   };
    key <AE12> {    [         equal,    equal equal ]   };

    //Row 2
    key <AD01> {    [             q,    Q       ]   };
    key <AD02> {    [             w,    W,      f o r parenleft i n t space i equal 0 semicolon space i space semicolon space i plus plus parenright space braceleft Enter Enter braceright Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left    ]   };
    key <AD03> {    [             e,    E,      s w i t c h parenleft parenright space braceleft Enter Enter braceright Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left,    c a s e space colon Enter space space Enter b r e a k semicolon Enter   ]   };
    key <AD04> {    [             r,    R,      i f parenleft parenright space braceleft Enter Enter braceright Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left ]   };
    key <AD05> {    [             t,    T,      space equal space space question space space colon space semicolon Left Left Left Left Left Left Left   ]   };
    key <AD06> {    [             y,    Y,      t r u e     ]   };
    key <AD07> {    [             u,    U,      f a l s e   ]   };
    key <AD08> {    [             i,    I,      b a c k g r o u n d parenleft parenright semicolon Enter Left Left Left ]   };
    key <AD09> {    [             o,    O,      s i z e parenleft comma space parenright semicolon Enter Left Left Left Left Left,  f u l l S c r e e n parenleft parenright semicolon Enter    ]   };
    key <AD10> {    [             p,    P       ]   };
    key <AD11> {    [     parenleft,    braceleft   ]   };//Switched bracketleft  with parenleft
    key <AD12> {    [    parenright,    braceright  ]   };//Switched bracketlright with parenright
    key <BKSL> {    [     backslash,    bar     ]   };

    //Row 3
    key <AC01> {    [             a,    A       ]   };
    key <AC02> {    [             s,    S,      v o i d space s e t u p braceleft Enter Enter braceright Up ]   };
    key <AC03> {    [             d,    D,      v o i d space d r a w braceleft Enter Enter braceright Up   ]   };
    key <AC04> {    [             f,    F,      i n t space,        i n t parenleft parenright Left     ]   };
    key <AC05> {    [             g,    G,      S t r i n g space,  s t r parenleft parenright Left     ]   };
    key <AC06> {    [             h,    H,      f l o a t space,    f l o a t parenleft parenright Left ]   };
    key <AC07> {    [             j,    J,      b o o l e a n space ]   };
    key <AC08> {    [             k,    K,      c l a s s space braceleft Enter Enter Enter Enter braceright Up Up Up Left Left Left    ]   };
    key <AC09> {    [             l,    L       ]   };
    key <AC10> {    [     semicolon,    colon       ]   };
    key <AC11> {    [    apostrophe,    quotedbl    ]   };

    //Row 4
    key <AB01> {    [             z,    Z       ]   };
    key <AB02> {    [             x,    X       ]   };
    key <AB03> {    [             c,    C       ]   };
    key <AB04> {    [             v,    V       ]   };
    key <AB05> {    [             b,    B       ]   };
    key <AB06> {    [             n,    N       ]   };
    key <AB07> {    [             m,    M       ]   };
    key <AB08> {    [         comma,    less,       less equal  ]   };
    key <AB09> {    [        period,    greater,    greater equal   ]   };
    key <AB10> {    [         slash,    question    ]   };

};
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: My belief is that what you try to do is not possible with XKB. Maybe it can be done via custom shortcuts instead.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson How would I do it via shortcuts?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe by mapping them to scripts. But my point was that I think XKB is a dead end. XKB is for typing single unicode characters.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I can try that?  I thought that XKB could do arrow keys, etc.

Comment: Are you talking about e.g. ▶ ? That's the Unicode character U+25B6.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No, arrow keys, like Left, Right, etc; to move the cursor around.